# Passwordless authentication on glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, joomla, glassfish, ejb

I'm developing a web application using Glassfish that has to be interfaced with an existing php web application that uses a Joomla CMS.

I would like to use glassfish Security Roles to secure the EJB's but doing so the users will be prompted to login when they leave joomla (That's used to login) for glassfish.

The idea:
**I'd like to login using the user's cookie/username stored inside user's browser.**

Question:
What's the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be using a servlet to capture the cookies and then logging in the user with

```
request.login(username, password);
```

More details on the official JavaEE tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html